# Simple pthreads and signal program on linux wont run

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, signals

This program is supposed to

The parent simply waits indefinitely for any child to return (hint, waitpid). 
b. The child sets up two signal handlers (hint, signal) and goes to sleep for 5 minutes. 
i. The first signal handler listens for the USR1 signal, and upon receiving it: 
1. Creates a thread (hint, pthread_create). 
a. Basically, all that the thread needs to do is “say hello” and sleep for 60 
seconds. 
ii. The second signal handler listens for the USR2 signal, and upon receiving it: 
1. Destroys the thread (hint, pthread_destroy).

My code compiles fine, just when I run it, absolutely nothing happens, not even the first printf which I put there as a test. Ive been staring at it for an hour and there are no errors, so why wont this run?

EDIT: This runs now, thanks charlie, however when it creates the thread, it outputs "[thread] sleeping for 1 m[thread] sleeping for 1 minute" and then ends, it never waits for the 2nd signal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

pthread_t thread;

void* temp()
{
    printf("[thread] hello professor\n");
    printf("[thread] sleeping for 1 minute\n");
    sleep(60);
}
void handle_USR1(int x)
{
    int s;
    printf("[signal] creating the thread\n");
    s = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &temp, NULL);
}

void handle_USR2(int x)
{
    int s;
    printf("[signal] destroying the thread\n");
    s = pthread_cancel(thread);
}

int main(void)
{
    int status = 0;

    if(fork() != 0)
    {
     printf("[parent] waiting.....\n");
     waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
    }
    else
    {
     printf("[child] to create the thread: kill -USR1 %d\n", getpid());
     printf("[child] to end the thread: kill -USR2 %d\n", getpid());
     printf("[child] setting up signal handlers\n");

     signal(SIGUSR1, handle_USR1);
     signal(SIGUSR2, handle_USR2);

     printf("[child] waiting for signals\n");
     sleep(300);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Add a newline to the initial printf to make it flush. Or call fflush. In fact, adding a newline to all your printfs will probably convince you it actually works. Also, checking fork() for -1 is a good idea.

Comment: @charlie what would adding a newline do? It never even prints the first "hello"

Comment: stdio is buffered, which means that characters sent to stdout don't get flushed until a newline is seen. Try it, just change printf("hello"); to printf("hello\n"); and you will see. I ran your code, it works.

Comment: holy crap, thank you so much. got to love the little weird things

Comment: new weird problem tho, it exits out of the process after the thread is created, never waits for the USR2 signal

Comment: man sigaction says that SIGUSR[12] terminate the process. So the waitpid() in the parent returns. I don't know how to prevent this. Sorry. Maybe ask another question with SIGUSR in the title to get a signal person to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a newline "\n" to all your printf's. Without it, stdout will not flush and it will appear your program is not working even though it is.

Also, checking fork() for failure is a good idea. fork() returns -1 on failure and sets errno.

Answer (score 1):

I landed on this question while searching something else and realized your program would terminate as soon as SIGUSR1 signal is processed. You need to wait for your thread like you're waiting for child process by issuing pthread_join

`void handle_USR1(int x)
    {
        int s;
        printf("[signal] creating the thread\n");
        s = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &temp, NULL);
        pthread_join(thread, NULL);
}`