# why SIGUSR1 kills my dd child process?

Tags: c, linux

Hi I have a simple function where i create a child process and parent process.

The child process suppose to run dd if=/some/file of=/somedisk.
The parent process suppose to run in a loop (until the child exists) and send signal SIGUSR1 which is forcing the dd in child process to report progress data.

Of course i have pipes where i redirect stdio and stderr from the child to the parent. (this i use in other functions and it works fine)

The problem i have is that:
1. I don't get anything on my stderr;
2. As soon as i send SIGUSR1 the process exits somehow.

```
    if(my_pid>0) //The parent part
            {

            close(FD_pipe_stdout[1]);// Parent process closes output side of the pipe 
            close(FD_pipe_stderr[1]);// Parent process closes output side of the pipe                               
            while(0==waitpid(my_pid, &my_pid_status, WNOHANG))
                {
                kill(my_pid, SIGUSR1); 
                sleep(1);
                //read(FD_pipe_stderr[0], pipe_error,PIPE_MAX_SIZE); // Read in a string from the stderror
                //puts(pipe_error);

                }
            puts("going out");
            read(FD_pipe_stdout[0], pipe_output,PIPE_MAX_SIZE); // Read in a string from the pipe's input side

            close(FD_pipe_stdout[0]);//on the end close the other side of pipe
            close(FD_pipe_stderr[0]);//on the end close the other side of pipe
            }         
   else
            {   // The child part
            close(FD_pipe_stdout[0]);/* Child process closes input side of the pipe */
            close(FD_pipe_stderr[0]);/* Child process closes input side of the pipe */
            dup2(FD_pipe_stdout[1],1); //redirect the stdout(1) to the fd_pipe and then close the sdtout
            dup2(FD_pipe_stderr[1],2);//redirect also stderr to the pipe
            system(dd if=/image.img of=/dev/sda);
            close(FD_pipe_stdout[1]); //on the end close the other side of pipe
            close(FD_pipe_stderr[1]); //on the end close the other side of pipe
            exit(0);
            }
```

I see on the screen that the parent is going out from the while loop and i don't understand why.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417272/pthreads-and-signal-handling-c-ending-early?noredirect=1#comment28784971_19417272

Comment: My guess would be that `system("dd ...")` is the problem. That uses the shell which probably does not catch SIGUSR1. Try `execlp("dd", "if=...", "of=...", NULL)` instead.

Comment: `system(dd if=/image.img of=/dev/sda);` it looks like there are some quotes missing here.

Comment: Yes. I forgot the quotes when i removed the parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`system()` creates a child process to run the specified command, so you really have three processes here:

1. The parent process (the one with the loop)
2. The child process (the one that calls `system()`
3. The *dd* process

You're signaling the child process instead of the *dd* process. SIGUSR1 by default causes a process to exit, so you're killing the child process.

To fix this, you could run *dd* using one of the `exec` functions, instead of calling `system()`:

```
{   // The child part
    close(FD_pipe_stdout[0]);
    close(FD_pipe_stderr[0]);
    dup2(FD_pipe_stdout[1],1);
    dup2(FD_pipe_stderr[1],2);
    execlp("dd", "dd", "if=/image.img", "of=/dev/sda", NULL);
    perror("exec failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

Now you only have two processes, because the child process becomes the *dd* process. When the parent signals the child, the signal will go to *dd*.

Note that there is a race condition here. The parent process may send a SIGUSR1 signal before *dd* starts and sets up its signal handler. To be robust, you should handle this somehow.

Comment: Note that `execlp()` requires a final `NULL` argument.